# What is a good approach to annotate invoice numbers for NER?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, python, natural-language, named-entity-recognition

I have a task for Document object detection. From bank reasons I need to extract several things. One of these things are invoice numbers.
The issue with invoice numbers is that one reason can contain more than one number and they may have various lengths. To make the task more interesting, since the reasons are written by humans they are never structured. The invoice(s) may be written in various ways. For example:

- 12345
- 12345, 12346, 12347
- 12345,12346
- 123801.802.803.804
- 0012300125 (missed separator)
- 001 002 006

I need to annotate the data before using it in a NER model.
My question is, what is the best way to annotate it - each invoice number separately (*006*), or the whole list as one annotation (for example, *12345, 12346, 12347*)?

I think the second approach may be better since there is no uniformity in the numbers and I just need to extract them.